# Firebase for multi-module projects

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, crashlytics-android

My project has 5 different modules, each containing a set of features which make up the whole application. 
The different modules are - app, domain, data, model and utility with utility being the base module which is inherited by every other module. 
All the modules have different package names - com.example.app, com.example.domain, com.example.utility, etc.

I want to access firebase methods from almost all the modules.

I wanted to know -

- Which package name should I register my app with on the console ?
- In which module's build.gradle should I add the google services plugin ?
- Where should I put the config file so that it's available to all the modules ?
- If I don't have any backend related data on Firebase and am only using it for Crashlytics and Analytics, will it be okay to open source the config file ?

What I tried ?

I registered my application using the app module package and added the config file in its directory. But when I tried running code from utility module, it didn't seem to work and gave an error regarding the FirebaseApp being not initialised.

```
    ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:184)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:112)
```

Comment: Firebase can only be configured per-app in the application module, not per library module.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate a little in terms of my problem :)

Comment: You asked "In which module's build.gradle should I add the google services plugin?", and I'm saying you have to use the application module for that.  You can't use the plugin on any other type of module.

Comment: I did that, but then i was not able to initialise it from other modules. Like I made a wrapper in the utility module but it gave the above error. 
Any thing that I might be possibly doing wrong ?